# Best Practices of hosting a node application for production

Tags: node.js, express, server, devops

I have to put a node application for live use and I was wondering if anyone could tell me the best practices around it.
The requirement is pretty simple for now, I have to host two node-applications in a Linux ubuntu server.
It would be of great help if someone could tell me the best practices around it.

1. What should be the port number(s) (best practice) in which I should be running the program on. [the node application exposes some endpoints which would be accessed by a mobile application]
2. Any tips on how to monitor server memory usage. [to set t
3. Any tips on optimizing the DB usage (mysql running in the same server)

   ```
   const pool = mysql.createPool({
   connectionLimit: 10,
   user: 'root',
   password: '<password>',
   host: '<IP>',
   database: '<DB>',
   port: '3306'
   ```

   });

What does the connection limit depend upon?

5. any more tips and tricks around it.

> Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If it's an app that a user types your domain into the browser bar, use port 80 (http) or 443 (https) so the user doesn't have to know the port.  Point #2 is mostly just a call for opinions (which is off-topic here) unless you have a more specific question.  Does point #3 mean memory usage by the server?  Point #4 is far, far too generic for anyone to know what to say.

Comment: I have updated the question a little to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

it won't be easy to answer some of the questions as we don't have enough details and they are quite general

1. 80 or 443 (depends if you need SSL or not, you will also need to create a cert with let's encrypt for example which is free) if it's something that's open for a user to access via the browser... if it's not it's up to you to select a port in the range that is not known by other applications usually... for example don't use mongo's port :)
2. I like PM2, matter of opinion since I can actually have multiple instances of the app running in cluster mode on one machine and then it also has auto restarts and such.
3. There are a lot of monitoring tools for Linux, just look for one that is in the budget you have and play around with it, I don't have any recommendation since i'm mostly using cloud solutions that have monitoring like that built in.
4. It's hard to tell you how to optimize queries without knowing that they are problematic or what queries... but... that being said, explain in mysql is your friend, run explain on the queries you have see that it uses the correct indexes etc, try reading about explain command in mysql
5. It all depends on how production ready you need to be... You can include things like pingdom or other monitoring tools or live profiling/monitoring tools like newrelic and such... This is a very general question and is always answered by the need of the person running the production environment so unless you provide us with exact needs of what you expect your system to do this is the best I can give you :) Also, look into things like sentry and there are other tools

But, to be honest... If this is just a simple application, why not go serverless like heroku and other solutions? you don't need to mess with all these things for the most part and you get monitoring and stuff as part of the package

Good luck.

Comment: @Shekhar NEVER RUN PRODUCTION CODE WITH THE ROOT USER :)
Too high privileges... Please make sure you create a special user for the application with only the privileges it needs to run and use that user...

Comment: `What does the connection limit depend upon?` - depends on the client you are using but usually it means how many connections it creates maybe? try reading the manual for the library you are using